# How to not display unwanted rows in query?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if we can prevent displaying unwanted items from MySQL without extra if statement conditions.

Example:  display all users except `!status=1`

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND status=?');
$stmt->execute([$email, $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Not I know how to do it with if statement.

Comment: as in, `status<>1`?

Comment: it's the same thing. just, `!=` isn't standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND status != ?');
$stmt->execute([$email, $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Take a look at https://www.educba.com/mysql-operators/